# Python file.write() taking two tries?

Tags: python, file-io

not  sure how to explain this, any help will be appreciated!

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Sep 15 2010, 16:22:56) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib2, pynotify, tempfile, os
>>> opener = urllib2.build_opener()
>>> page = opener.open('http://img.youtube.com/vi/RLGJU_xUVTs/1.jpg')
>>> thumb = page.read()
>>> temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.jpg')
>>> temp.write(thumb)
>>> os.path.getsize(temp.name)
0
>>> temp.write(thumb)
>>> os.path.getsize(temp.name)
4096
```

thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you open the `thumb` file, you'll see that there's one whole copy and a partial copy of the data that you are writing in it.

flush the file instead of writing a second time.

```
temp.flush()
```

The file wasn't writing the first time because the contents aren't large enough to fill the buffer. The second write overfills the buffer and so a buffer's worth of data gets written.

As Cameron points out in his answer, the buffer is automatically flushed when you close the file. If you want to keep it open for some reason (and the fact that this is an issue for you seems to indicate that you do), then you can call `flush` and the data will be written right away.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't called `flush()` or `close()` on the file object before checking its size on disk -- there is an internal buffer that is automatically flushed only after a certain amount of data is written (this avoids too many expensive trips to the disk when doing many writes).

Comment: thanks! flush() has done it, however calling close() deletes the file, i assume b/c it's a tempfile.

Comment: @aaronasterling: Yeah, I don't actually know the implementation of `tempfile` objects in Python, so I originally said "maybe" -- but of course the posted code demonstrates the existence of said buffer (and it would be kinda crazy if there weren't a buffer anyway). `close` was the first thing that occurred to me that would flush the buffer (and then I saw your answer, slapped my forehead, and edited). +1 to your answer BTW -- apparently `close` deletes the temporary file, so not the right answer in this case :-)